# UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: - include file extensions or no?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Are there any negative implications of excluding the file extension when using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` or is it best to include the file type in the path?

The Apple Docs state that `initWithContentsOfFile:` requires the following path as its parameter:

> The path to the file. This path should include the filename extension that identifies the type of the image data.

However, the path for `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` just states:

> The full or partial path to the file.

I was just wondering if it's still best practice to include the file extension or to not even worry about it.  Thanks!

Comment: Side note - At the bottom of the documentation page there is a link to report problems. You should report this inconsistency. The `imageWithContentsOfFile:` method is just a shortcut to calling `initWithContentsOfFile:` so they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the file extension for all file requests.  The only instance I can think of where you would not is using the

```
NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:
```

method.  That method you specify the file extension outside of the file name.  I'm relatively certain the "partial path" refers to relative paths.  You can ask for a file in the root of your bundle by just the file name as it's path relative to your bundle is in the root, in other words just the file name.

Comment: When using `UIImage imageNamed:` you are only supposed to specify the root of the image name. No extension, no `@2x` or other suffix.

Comment: @rmaddy since iOS4 the extension is optional, but only if the file is a PNG.

Comment: @JamesP Yes, I should have mentioned that this is only valid for png images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:`

If you have those images:

- "myImage.png" (iPhone)
- "myImage@2x.png" (iPhone Retina)

And you want to load it to an `UIImage`, you will use this code:

```
UIImage *myImage;
myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSBundle pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"]];
```

This code will also load the "myImage@2x.png" in iPhone Retina with no need to add the @2x to the code.

Be sure to write the exact file name. "myimage" might not work on device since the original file name has a Uppercase "I" ("myImage.png").